# problems after migration of a foxpro app from novell to samba

Tags: samba, novell, erp

I had to decomission an old novell server which served for shares in a medium network (~30 workstations) and chose a virtualized samba solution (freebsd under vmware esxi)

after the first two weeks, I have the following feedback:

- all apps and files are ok when served from the new share; speed is ok

except

- an old foxpro app which runs in ms-dos mode, exectuable is ran from the share and it takes a very long time to run from remote clients (brought inside the lan with openvpn)
- sometimes the foxpro app freezes on the local workstations, but generally inside the lan it is acceptable

the question is what is the difference between the shares created under novell and samba that it has such a big impact on this ancient app ? clients are all windows xp, no firewall and the antivirus not scanning files from the mapped drives

if needed, I can provide a testparm output

Comment: How was the Novell directory shared -- was it via CIFS/SMB or were you using the Novell client (NCP)? Out of the box I would expect NCP to be more reliable than CIFS via Samba.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling oplocks:

level2 oplocks = no

oplocks = no

Comment: same result ...